# Java Calendar returns wrong date

Tags: java, calendar

I tried a bunch of things and this one seemed to be the most promising, but there are still discrepancies.

I have an interval *(Start & End-Date always within one month)* and I want to know how many days this month has. Also I wanted to make sure, that Start- and End-Date are within the same month. But this doesn't work due to the dates Calendar returns. Here is my code and my stacktrace:

```
Calendar cstart = Calendar.getInstance();
cstart.setTime(startInterval);
Calendar cend = Calendar.getInstance();
cstart.setTime(endInterval);

int daysInMonth = cstart.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

if (cstart.get(Calendar.MONTH) != cend.get(Calendar.MONTH)) {
    throw new FacadeException(AccountingFacadeMessages.BILLING_NOT_WITHIN_MONTH);
}

LOG.info("EndInterval " + endInterval.toString() );
LOG.info("StartInterval " + startInterval.toString() );
LOG.info(cstart.get(Calendar.DATE) + "." + cstart.get(Calendar.MONTH) + "." + cstart.get(Calendar.YEAR));
LOG.info("Days: " + daysInMonth + "\n");
```

Stacktrace:

```
2018-01-23 13:50:15,328: [INFO]  EndInterval Sun Dec 31 00:00:00 CET 2017
2018-01-23 13:50:15,329: [INFO]  StartInterval Fri Dec 01 00:00:00 CET 2017
2018-01-23 13:50:15,329: [INFO]  31.11.2017
2018-01-23 13:50:15,329: [INFO]  Days: 31
```

Of course with this, the Exception gets thrown. For the stacktrace, I placed the Exception in a comment.

Thanks a lot :)

**EDIT**: `cstart.get(Calendar.MONTH) != cend.get(Calendar.MONTH)` throws an exception, when the month isn't the same. My start date is 1/12/2017 and enddate is 31/12/2017. so the month should be the same, but isn't, becuase Calender returns 31/11/2017 instead of 1/12/2017. So the exception gets thrown all the time. I really need the correct dates.

**EDIT**: 
new Stacktrace:

Interval: 1.12.2017 - 31.12.2017:

```
2018-01-23 14:38:28,005: [INFO] endInterval.toString(): Sun Dec 31  00:00:00 CET 2017
2018-01-23 14:38:28,005: [INFO] Calendar returns: 23.0.2018
2018-01-23 14:38:28,006: [INFO] startInterval.toString(): Fri Dec 01 00:00:00 CET 2017
2018-01-23 14:38:28,006: [INFO] Calendar returns: 31.11.2017
```

Interval: 1.11.2017 - 30.11.2017:

```
2018-01-23 14:38:52,398: [INFO] endInterval.toString(): Thu Nov 30 00:00:00 CET 2017
2018-01-23 14:38:52,399: [INFO] Calendar returns: 23.0.2018
2018-01-23 14:38:52,399: [INFO] startInterval.toString(): Wed Nov 01 00:00:00 CET 2017
2018-01-23 14:38:52,399: [INFO] Calendar returns: 30.10.2017
```

Comment: and what exactly is wrong?

Comment: i'm confused as to what this means: Of course with this, the Exception gets thrown. For the stacktrace, I placed the Exception in a comment.

Comment: The date in the third Info should be 01.Dec.2017, if anyone's wondering :D

Comment: @dienerd cstart.get(Calendar.MONTH) != cend.get(Calendar.MONTH) throws an exception, when the month isn't the same. My start date is 1/12/2017 and enddate is 31/12/2017. so the month should be the same, but isn't, becuase Calender returns 31/11/2017 instead of 1/12/2017. So the exception gets thrown all the time. I really need the correct dates

Comment: @Lorayne can you include this and the exact Exception/stack trace in the post. the original post is confusing. it helps to have all pertinent data in the original question rather than relying on people to go through all the comments

Comment: @dienerd I'd love to provide a stacktrace for the Exception, but it's empty because I added the constraint if (cstart.get(Calendar.MONTH) != cend.get(Calendar.MONTH)) {
       throw new FacadeException(
               AccountingFacadeMessages.BILLING_NOT_WITHIN_MONTH);
    }

I'm sorry if I can't make clear, what my problem is. English is not my first language and sometimes I'm not sure if everyone understands what I want xD

Comment: @Lorayne you are passing the wrong parameter.

Comment: The `Calendar` class is long outdated. I recommend you stop using it and use `java.time.LocalDate` instead. It is so much nicer to work with and may eventually also replace your homegrown date class. More details in [johnII’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48402651/5772882).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem isn't the `Date` class, but passing the wrong parameter.

Change:

```
cstart.get(Calendar.DATE)
```

to

```
cstart.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
```

EDIT: This does not solve the issue.
There does seem to be some problem, but since the OP is using in-house developed Date/.. classes, I 'm not going to pursue this further. 
For those who want more information about that, check the comments.

Comment: I tried this one and I still get 31.11.2017 for 1.12.2017

Also I tried the endInterval, which became 23.0.2018  instead of 31.12.2017 :D I'm very confused :D

Comment: what value do you have for your original startInterval and endInterval?

Comment: My Stacktrace-Info says Start = Dec 01 2017 and End = Dec 31 2017. I can post a new one

Comment: can you show the code where you set the values? for now, all you've shown is a String representation

Comment: I'll try to find it. I didn't write the whole program alone :D One second :)

Comment: it seems to be linked to the month. When I perform it on an odd number for month, it gets the endday, if I perform it on an even number for month, it takes the correct one. might be something in the Date instantiation, but anyway, I agree you shouldn't use dates like this anymore. most of the material is deprecated and replaced by better material

Comment: Thank you, maybe I should talk with my employer about it. He wrote most of the code and created an own class for Dates. I already told him, that his class always leads to problems, because I must convert it to Calendar a couple of times. I will take a look into better material then :)

Comment: @Lorayne actually ... that kind of changes ... a lot. since we have no idea of knowing what your Date class does, or how it behaves, we can't know what it does. but as for as the java Date class, I would recommend following johnll 's advice.

Comment: Okay I thought, because the toString()-method provides the correct date, that there is nothing wrong with the Date Class.
Thanks for the help. I'll look into the Date class and the suggestions :)

Comment: The docs say that both `DATE` and `DAY_OF_MONTH` are “Field number for get and set indicating the day of the month.” So how could your answer make any difference?

Comment: @OleV.V. during the afterward comments and checking I figured that out as well, I just didn't remove the answer to keep the comments (in which more information can be found by others)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use the new time api of Java 8 instead, its not confusing as the previous jdk Date/Calendar api.

```
final DateTimeFormatter sdf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
final LocalDate end = LocalDate.of(2017, 12, 31);
final LocalDate start = LocalDate.of(2017, 12, 1);

System.out.println("end : " + sdf.format(end));
System.out.println("start : " + sdf.format(start));

if (end.getMonth() != start.getMonth()) {
    throw new Exception("Month not equal");
}
```

Comment: though recommendable, this doesn't actually answer the question at hand

Answer (score 0):

It works as expected. The months are 0-based. I.e. January is 0, December is 11.

Comment: Check the comments, she's talking about 31 being printed instead of 1

Comment: Yes I thought so, but somehow I need to work with this and I don't know how.